# Chomsky-Schützenberger for Deterministic CFLs

Tags: regular-language, context-free, homomorphism

Is there a [Chomsky-Schützenberger representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_representation_theorem) for deterministic CFLs?  Knowing precisely the class of morphisms [under which DCFL is closed](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-31653-1_15), such a theorem would probably be of the form:

> $L$ is a DCFL iff $L = h(R \cap D_k)$ for $D_k$ the Dyck on $k$
>   parentheses, $R$ a regular language, and $h$ a code with bounded
>   delay.

Does it hold? Does it appear anywhere?